# Default Spacing of Figure/Table-Enviroment

Tags: default

I could find it on the web. Is there a default vertical Spacing of the Figure/Table-Enviroment between the text and the picture/tabular in pt? I'm looking for the red marked space in the following picture:

[image]

Comment: you haven't shown any code so i am guessing that is a `[h]` float rather than `[b]` so `\intextsep` which is set by your document class `\the\intextsep` will print the value, for debugging

Comment: I see no red marked space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that the following list gives you what you want.

```
\floatsep        space between floats (default 12pt)
\textfloatsep    space between a top (bottom) float and suceeding (preceeding) text (default 20pt)  
\intextsep       space above/below an [h] float (default 12pt)
\dblfloatsep     like \floatsep for double column floats (default 12pt)
\dbltextfloatsep like \textfloatsep for double column floats (default 20pt)
```

You can check any of these for your particular document by `\the\...sep` which will print the value in your printed output.

```
\documentclass{...}
\begin{document}
The textfloatsep is \the\textfloatsep.
\end{document}
```